# Gradle not working properly after Update · Cannot run the flutter app

Tags: flutter

My flutter project is long time at here not showing any error.That is start at sep 18,2022.I cannot run and test the codes.Please help me all.Thanks.

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Comment: try invalid cache from android studio.

Comment: Check gradle wrapper version on `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and gradle build on `android/build.gradle`.

Comment: You should post your error logs here so we can help you detect problems